# Listing USB Devices with C# and WMI

Tags: c#, usb, wmi

I'm trying to implement a function in my application that lists all the plugged in USB Mass Storage Devices in a computer.

My code works well when launching the application but my problem is that I want the box in my form to refresh automatically when a USB device is removed or attached.

Implementing DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL and DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE conditions should work but I get back a "DisconnectedContext was detected" exception.

I learned that I need to use a delegate and set an asyncronous call for this to work correctly.

Here's my code:

```
          public void listUSB()
      {
        ManagementScope sc = new ManagementScope(wmiUsbList);

        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("select * from Win32_DiskDrive " + "where InterfaceType='USB'");

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(sc, query);
        ManagementObjectCollection result = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject obj in result)
            {
                 if (obj["DeviceID"] != null)
                        {
                            usbListTextBox.AppendText(obj["Model"].ToString());
                        }
            }

      }
```

I'd really like to know how to apply a delegate to my method.

I also looked at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ea183afd-d070-4abd-8e00-a1784fdfedc5/) thread on MSDN which provides an excellent example, but as of that example I am not able to understand how to put the deviceList in a textbox.

I'm still Learning so if someone could be so kind to point me to the right direction on one or both of my questions, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ManagementEventWatcher` and assign an event handler to the `EventArrived`.

I don't know how to accomplish exactly this, but here is a watcher that listens to the print events:

```
string printQuery = "Select * From __InstanceCreationEvent Within 1 Where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PrintJob'";
string nspace = @"\\.\root\CIMV2";
var watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(nspace, printQuery);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private usbListArrayDelegate mDeleg;

      protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
      {
          int devType;
          base.WndProc(ref m);

          switch (m.WParam.ToInt32())
          {
              case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:

                  devType = Marshal.ReadInt32(m.LParam, 4);

                  if (devType == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
                  {
                      // usb device inserted, call the query       
                      mDeleg = new usbListArrayDelegate(usbListArray);
                      AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(usbListArrayCallback);


                      // invoke the thread that will handle getting the friendly names   
                      mDeleg.BeginInvoke(callback, new object());   

                  }

                  break;

              case DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:       

                  devType = Marshal.ReadInt32(m.LParam, 4);

                  if (devType == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME)
                  {
                      mDeleg = new usbListArrayDelegate(usbListArray);
                      AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(usbListArrayCallback);


                      // invoke the thread that will handle getting the friendly names   
                      mDeleg.BeginInvoke(callback, new object());   
                  }

                  break;
         }
      }

      public ArrayList usbListArray()
      {
          ArrayList deviceList = new ArrayList();

           manager = new UsbManager();   ==> about how to implement this please see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/63878/Enumerate-and-Auto-Detect-USB-Drives

          UsbDiskCollection disks = manager.GetAvailableDisks();

          foreach (UsbDisk disk in disks)
          {
              deviceList.Add(disk);              
          }

          return deviceList;
      }   

      // delegate wrapper function for the getFriendlyNameList function   
      private delegate ArrayList usbListArrayDelegate();

      // callback method when the thread returns   
      private void usbListArrayCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
      {
          string ArrayData = string.Empty;
          // got the returned arrayList, now we can do whatever with it   
          ArrayList result = mDeleg.EndInvoke(ar);

          int count = 0;

          foreach (UsbDisk disk in result)
          {
              ++count;

              ArrayData += count + ") " + disk.ToString().
           }
```